# Well working and comprehensive ADT for C

Tags: c, abstract-data-type

Is there any good implementation of ADT library for C programming language? Implementing Lists, HashMaps, Sets, Stacks, Queues, LinkedLists etc? I know this is kinda stupid question but i wouldn't like to implement all of these just to realize that it's already out there.

I saw shreds of them all over the Internet - of course. But is there any comprehensive all-in-one well-working solution that any of you have good experience with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glib is one good example, as the previous post suggested.

Another is looking at [redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/) - it has several nice utilities - a hash table, dynamic string, etc. The code is much simpler than Glib and is well written and easy to understand.

Answer (score 6):

Glib is a pretty reliable and powerful library: [http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/2.22](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/2.22/)

It has tables, Linked lists etc, etc. I found it a little bit intimidating but it's just a matter of personal preference.